# Did the concept of Heaven as the dwelling place of God where the chosen ones join Him for eternity, gradually develop?

Tags: catholicism, old-testament, heaven, new-testament

We see many instances in the OT in which prominent people die and are  gathered to their  people, for example: Abraham (Gen 25:8) Ishmael (Gen 25:17 ), Isaac( Gen 35:29). There is no mention of the place where `their people'  were dwelling after their death.

We first see  usage of the term  "heaven" in Gen 21: 17:

> God heard the boy crying, and the angel of God called to Hagar from heaven and said to her, “What is the matter, Hagar? Do not be afraid; God has heard the boy crying as he lies there.

We also see  reference in Deut 4:6 and 4:39.

So, "Heaven"in the Old Testament is described as the place where God the Father dwells, and not as a place where the justified ones join Him for eternity.

In the New Testament, we first come across the mention of Heaven in Mtt3:1-2 (In those days John the Baptist came, preaching in the wilderness of Judea  and saying, “Repent, for the kingdom of heaven has come near.” ) and Mtt 5: 3 ("Blessed are the poor in spirit,    for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.").

Jesus, alludes  to Heaven when he says in Lk 16:22:

> The time came when the beggar died and the angels carried him to Abraham’s side.

So, the concept of Heaven as the dwelling place of God in which all the justified ones(including the chosen ones who had joined their forefathers after death)  join Him for eternity,  is something which gradually developed .

My question therefore is: According to Catholic scholars, did the concept of Heaven as the dwelling place of God where the chosen ones join Him for eternity, gradually develop?

Comment: I think you go too far in the assertion that '"Heaven"in the Old Testament is described as the place where God the Father dwells, and not as a place where the justified ones join Him for eternity.' The only thing your examples show is that Heaven in the OT (specifically, in the 5 books of the law) is the place where God dwells. It says nothing one way or the other on whether the souls of the just go there to be with Him. Catholic tradition, too, actually hold that the souls of the just did not go to heaven in the OT. They waited in a kind of limbo for Christ to die and release their souls.

Comment: In Gen 21:17, "from heaven" (specific place) could be "from the sky" (general area), or "from above" (general direction).
¶ Matthew wrote for a Jewish audience, so used the euphemism "Kingdom of Heaven", not "Kingdom of God", to avoid invoking the Name.
¶ Luke 16:22 makes no mention of "heaven".
¶ While God inhabits "the third heaven" (2 Col 12:2), nothing says that any dead human would ever go to heaven.
John 3:13 explicitly states "*no one has ascended to heaven but … the Son of Man* [Jesus]".
¶ "*the concept of Heaven as … where the chosen ones join Him*" is entirely post-biblical.

Comment: "Deut 4:6" is a typo?